# Can't include x-editable to Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, x-editable, ruby-on-rails-6

I trying to include x-editable framework to my project, but it doesn't work.

If I download framework (from http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) and include it in **packs/** directory, I see `TypeError: $(...).editable is not a function` in console.

If I include `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.1/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>` to **/layouts/application.html.slim**, the error message will change

`TypeError: this.tip(...) is undefined`

By the way, in **javascript/packs/application.js** I including to project needed frameworks (as I guesss):

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require('bootstrap')
require("jquery")
require('packs/announcements')
require('packs/bootstrap-tooltip')
require('packs/bootstrap-popover')
require('packs/bootstrap-editable')
require('packs/bootstrap-editable.min')
```

Function 'tip' defined in **bootstrap-tooltip.js** but cdnjs.cloudflare.com doesn't know about it. What am I doing wrong and how to connect x-editable to my project?

P.S.
Other parts related with x-editable including I have in my project:

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'x-editable-rails'
```

**assets/javascripts/application.js:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require editable/bootstrap-editable
//= require editable/rails
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using Webpacker, but, if you are you can do the following:

1) Add the yarn package

```
yarn add x-editable
```

2) In your `application.js` or if you are also using Stimulus you can put this in your controller file

```
require('x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable')
require('x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable')
```

Not that x-editable is not compatible with Bootstrap 4, but it pretty much looks ok.